# Flatten transparency in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, tikz-external, transparency

I have a document which I need to compile PDF/A-1b compatible, which means that transparency is not allowed.

I have (several) `tikz` sources directly in the document, and I think they look better with transparency. I have to check if this holds true when flattened.

For flattening transparency, I have seen that `ps2pdf -dHaveTransparency=false` (or `ps2pdf13`) should work on pdfs. Is there a way to use `tikz` or `LaTeX` directly to flatten transparency?

Comment: No insofar as *TeX can not manipulate included PDFs on the fly (LuaTeX can in theory); you need external programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TeX can not manipulate included PDFs on the fly (LuaTeX can in theory); you need external programs, so **no**.